# How do I authenticate a trusted app using OAUTH 2

Tags: php, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am developing an OAUTH 2 REST API for a website I am working on. We have an official native mobile app which uses this API and is planning to make the API open to third party developers.
Our native mobile app will be having more permissions than the 3rd party apps. I am doing that by setting permissions based on client id or app id. 
I am using `password` `grant type` for the official app and `implicit` `grant type` for the 3rd party apps.

But the problem is that as we are not using a `client_secret` in either cases a 3rd party may be able to get elevated permissions by somehow stealing our official `client_id` and using it to get access to the elevated permissions in the API which is exclusive to the official app.

Is there anyway to prevent them from doing that ? How does the Official Facebook or Twitter app do it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use tokens that is a hash of this information *(`client_id`, `Official app`, `day`, ...)* for the application

> the 'Day' in order to get every day a new token that minimize the risque

and  this tokens for 3rd party *(`client_id`, `3rd party`, ...)*
So in your API add a function to get information from tokens

> All Requests from Api have to be over SSL which are then validated at server to decide if the request is to be processed/dropped.

Comment: I didn't understand. You are saying I should use OAuth tokens with the (client_id, Official app, day, ...) etc. in it in the API when the client requests for a token.
What difference is it going to make ?  And what do you mean by `Official app` ?

Comment: 'Official app' and '3rd party' are a string or a code with it you can identify the source of request;